# Modify an .asm file with vb.net application on run time

Tags: vb.net, oop, assembly

I'm working on a personal project and i decided to make some kind of theremin but instead of radio frequencies, i want to make it with code.

I found how to make sound with asm on [this](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/make-sound-from-the-speaker-in-assembly/8255-8255-8284-asm-program-example.asp)site (very helpful).
And i do have a sensor that sends me a certain voltage depending on distance of my hand and i can read it with an application in vb.net(HID).

Now my question is that is it possible to manipulate an .asm file on the run time with vb.net so i can make a sound with asm depending of the value that my sensor is giving me?

i have been looking for some information with Google, but it seems that i'm not typing the right tags.

Comment: Would it not be easier to generate/play the sound in the VB code?

Comment: yeah, i know, but its also to exempt a subject in my school and i need to use asm language

Comment: I think you have a nice challenge there! In brief you would need to write a DLL in x86 assembler, with one or more functions to control the sound, and then `PInvoke` those functions from your VB.NET application. I googled `asm dll creation` and got this: http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/create-asm-dll-win32/create-asm-dll-win32.asp.

Comment: Note that that is still only an assembler template for a DLL. You will still need to somehow package an assembler or find/write one in C#.